Can you cancel an FCC application for a vanity callsign?
Sometimes when you check for available callsigns at websites such as radioqth, you find more than one callsign available on different days, but within a close range ... such as only 10 days apart. Should I apply for the earlier one, then apply for the later one? Wait until both are available but the earlier one likely has applicants already? If granted the earlier one, would that automatically cancel the second application, or would I cancel it (and is that even possible?)?  I've been trying for a 1x2 or 2x1 for over a year now and am trying to figure out how to increase my odds... Help?

The post added context as to why I may need or want to cancel.  That's the way I post.


Should I apply for the earlier one, then apply for the later one?

If you want.

Wait until both are available but the earlier one likely has applicants already?

With a 1x2 or a 2x1 if you don't apply on the first (business) day it's available, there's pretty much no point in applying at all. Someone else will have, and the lottery will almost certainly go to one of the people who applied on that first day (except in the rare case that they all got an earlier choice on their list). So I wouldn't go this route.

If granted the earlier one, would that automatically cancel the second application

Yes. If you're granted a callsign change request (vanity or sequential), any vanity applications under your old callsign will be dismissed.

Good info - although I think their random selection of who gets an applied-for callsign is independent of application date, e.g. random, not first come first serve.

@IdahoTaterHead all the applications on a given day are processed in a random order. If someone gets it one day, then clearly no later application is going to get it.
